# Associating special meaning with user id 0

Tags: plugin-development, database, id, customization

I'm writing a plugin that creates a custom table holding data which is linked to a user account with a `user_id` field. Now if that users account would be deleted for any reason I would like to set that `user_id` field in my custom table to `0` to keep the stored data in an anonymized fashion.

Since the first user `ID` is `1` and counted upwards from there I would assume this is save. Is there any reason why this might have unwanted side effects?

Also, if I would add key constraints to my custom table this would obviousle be a problem when `0` is not existent in `wp_users`. Would it be hazardous to add a fake user record with id `0` to `wp_users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the most semantic solution: If I want to relate a given row of data to "nowhere", `NULL` is the best value to reflect that. And it even works with constraints on the field!